# Does redeclaring an argument in a Lua function as a local variable make any difference in performance?

Tags: performance, lua

I'm doing a code review and I'm seeing code where the author wants to change the argument passed in, and instead of just changing the argument variable directly, redefines it with `local`, like this:

```
function doThing(x)
    local x = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    return x
end
```

I understand having the `local` there is unnecessary, since the argument is already local to the function, however I'm unsure if there's any impact on performance by doing this (for example, if `x` is a large table and sticks around shadowed when the variable is redefined with `local x`).

Is there any difference in performance between the example above and the following way of writing it without `local`?

```
function doThing(x)
    x = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    return x
end
```

Comment: Is the environment the code runs in LuaJIT?

Comment: Seems like the only difference is that with `local x` you've created a second local variable in the function that shadows the first one in the argument list. I bet the difference in performance is very slight and is almost unnoticeable.

Comment: I think a comment in the code to indicate the intent is called for. (That's my basic rule for questions that come up during code review, anyway.) It's hard to address the question when it is based on a supposition.